# Requested store is not found

Tags: magento2, database

I've migrated my database of my store when access store front or admin panel I get the following error

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found   
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found #0 \app\code\Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository.php(124): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById('1')   
#1 \app\code\Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver.php(167): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getActiveStoreById('1') 
#2\app\code\Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver.php(98): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getDefaultStoreById('1')  
#3\app\code\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager.php(154): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId()  
#4\var\generation\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy.php(119): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore(NULL)   
#5 \app\code\Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store.php(29): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL)   
#6 \lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL)   
#7 \lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL)   
#8 \var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('admin/url/use_c...', 'stores', NULL)   
#9 \app\code\Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver.php(96): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->getValue('admin/url/use_c...', 'store')   
#10 \app\code\Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver.php(79): Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->isHostBackend()    
#11 \lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\AreaList.php(73): Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName(true)   
#12 \lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Http.php(130): Magento\Framework\App\AreaList->getCodeByFrontName('admin_6y3w8w')    
#13 \lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()    
#14 \index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))    
#15 {main}
```

Comment: this might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156176/magento-2-requested-store-is-not-found