# Requested store not found

Tags: database, magento2.2.7

I am having an issue with stores, magento is trying to find a store by id '3', it doesn't exist, due to which most of the functionality is not working. Website was migrated from 1.9.2.4 to 2.2.7, I have checked both databases for the store ID but it only exists in the new database.

I have checked [Magento 2: Requested store is not found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156176/magento-2-requested-store-is-not-found)

But it isn't related to my issue and not working.

After some digging I found that store ID '3' should infact be '5' as that is the store which customers belong to. 
I am trying to run a db query that changes store_id to 5 from 3, is this good practice or there is another way? How do I perform this for whole database instead of one table as in the query below.

```
UPDATE  `MySQL_Table` SET  `MySQL_Table_Column` = REPLACE(`MySQL_Table_Column`, 'oldString', 'newString') WHERE  `MySQL_Table_Column` LIKE 'oldString%';
```

Comment: I guess that your issue at data migration.Might be setting migration is  not working properly

Comment: Could be but is my proposed solution a good one?

Comment: Yes, my proposed solution worked, also used sql search to find the tables with the id that was giving the error