# Magento 2: Customer Registration Rest API throws error

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento2.3.0, customer-registration

I try to register customer via Rest API. But customer registration Rest API throwing error.

> Method: POST
>
> Request URL: http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/customers

`Body:`

```
{
    "customer": {
        "email": "jdoea@example.com",
        "firstname": "Jane",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "addresses": [{
            "defaultShipping": true,
            "defaultBilling": true,
            "firstname": "Jane",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "region": {
                "regionCode": "NY",
                "region": "New York",
        "regionId":43
            },
            "postcode": "10755",
            "street": ["123 Oak Ave"],
            "city": "Purchase",
            "telephone": "512-555-1111",
            "countryId": "US"
        }]
    },
    "password": "test@$123"
}
```

`Response:`

```
    <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in
<b>/var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php</b> on line <b>74</b><br />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience this kind of error is related to a recursive method that it calls upon itself in an infinite loop.

I would suggest to check the newest changes made to the project or the latest modules installed.

Comment: I have already checked to disabled custom and third party module. But not working.

Comment: did you also cleared the cache? if you are using redis, try to connect to the server and a FLUSHALL command.

Comment: Yes flushed the cache.

Answer (score 5):

In case of anyone wondering, I've had the exact same issue in my Magento 2.3.5 multisite setup when calling the /rest/V1/customers REST endpoint.

I've solved the issue by specifying the store_id parameter in my customer object:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "firstname": "test",
        "lastname": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "store_id": 1,
        "extension_attributes": {
            "is_subscribed": false
        }
    },
    "password": "Account@123"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change method GET to POST**
Pass Authentication key in header

```
Authorization: Bearer key
```

Comment: Tried with same but not working.

Comment: Try with this url - http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/V1/customers

Comment: I have tried but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use xdebug in Magento 2, but it will require modifying [the default max_nesting_level value of 100 that xdebug uses.](https://xdebug.org/docs/index.php?action=basic#max_nesting_level)

Open up the php.ini file being used by your server and update or add the following config, depending on if it already exists in your file:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 320
```

This works for me, but if you still see the error you can try doubling the value again.

Comment: Not working I have tried with value 450 and then 1000

Comment: This is server related issue, try to increase space, execution time, memory limit etc at server level

Comment: I am working in my local instance. Also this API working fine in native Magento 2 instance. It is issue in my this project instance only.

Comment: This is all about server problem, whether you are on local or instance.

Comment: Yes. But how we can resolve.