# Magento 2 - "The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again."

Tags: magento2, store-view, stores

If I call `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get:

> “The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try
> again.”

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by disabling the module Litespeed_Litemage

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that one of your setup scripts is failing. Check `system.log`,`debug.log` or `exception.log` in `var/log` directory to see if you can get a stack trace to find the problematic script.

Comment: Nothing in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below possible solution for this. Before executing the below queries, Please checks the respected values in the database table.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue but it related to a multi-store setup. With Litespeed active, it default to a store of ID 1. We had to manually set this to avoid it applying the default store ID and causing an error in indexing, upgrading etc.

Setting is under Configuration > Advanced > Litemage Cache

[image: Litemage Settings]

Thanks to Silas Palmer on this post for debugging tips: [Magento 2: Requested store is not found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156176/magento-2-requested-store-is-not-found)